# Formatting for separate rows per column using Pandas pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data:

```py
data = [
    {
        "Account": "Cash",
        "amount": 10,
        "direction": "debit",
    },
    {
        "Account": "Cash",
        "amount": 10,
        "direction": "credit",
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.pivot(index="Account", columns="direction", values="amount")
```

The value of `pivot()` outputs the following:

```
direction  credit  debit
Account                 
Cash           10     10
```

What I actually want, however, is something akin to:

```
direction  credit  debit
Account                 
Cash           10     
Cash                  10
```

That is, I want all of the "credit" lines to be on a separate row as "debit" for formatting purposes (ie, when using `to_table()` or `to_csv()`).

I've tried using `to_dict()`, manipulating the result, and recreating a dataframe using `from_dict()` but this has become fairly tricky with multi-indexes.

The only way I can think to do this is to take the data as a dictionary and manually format and output. Is there a way to do this separation in pandas itself?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [`set_index(..., append=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
df.set_index(['Account', 'direction'], append=True)['amount'].unstack(-1)

direction  credit  debit
  Account               
0 Cash        NaN   10.0
1 Cash       10.0    NaN
```

using `append=True`, we can have differentiate each "Cash" row using the existing index so they don't collapse into a single row when pivoting/unstackin